# Retrieve Values from NSDictionary

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have the following values in NSDictionary.

```
{"data":[
    {"name":"Cem Aykutalp","id":"1538278008"},
    {"name":"Pasqual Martin","id":"1841753129"},
    {"name":"Yusuf Do\u011fan","id":"100000024057687"},
    {"name":"New Wave","id":"100000409270728"},
    {"name":"DanRey Dumalag","id":"100000446097675"},
    {"name":"Rushikesh Dhruva","id":"100000603556855"},
    {"name":"Ricsi Zov\u00e1nyi","id":"100001018351273"},
    {"name":"Pero Peri\u0107","id":"100002192083309"},
    {"name":"Ayse Suer","id":"100002502298417"},
    {"name":"Miranda Johnson","id":"100002554868458"}
 ]}
```

How can I retrieve name and id tag from that Dictionary.

Comment: To save you some time, since it seems like you're going to ask a question about every JSON dictionary you encounter. It's all JSON and you need to parse it with one of JSON libraries I mentioned in your other question. :)

Comment: @macbirdie   Did you have any running code by using your JSON Libraries??Plz Provide if exist

Comment: Those are not *my* libraries; they're publicly accessible libraries and I'm sure there are many tutorials available on the web. You have to show some minimal amount of research done if you want anyone to help you. Don't ask for food. Ask how to make it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSString *name = [[[yourDict objectForKey:@"data"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"name"];
NSString *yourId = [[[yourDict objectForKey:@"data"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"id"];
```

this is only for 1st array, if you want to get all the name's and id's from yourDict than use a for loop.